# Justification for continuing a complex function based on isolines of its magnitude.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

The diagram below shows the isolines of the magnitude of a complex function $f(z)$ where $z$ is complex.

For the purposes of this question, the values of $f(z)$ are only known for $\operatorname{Re}(z)>a$. The diagram shows the isolines are smooth but are cut off at $\operatorname{Re}(z)=a$.

My intuition is that the function *must* continue smoothly to the left into $\operatorname{Re}(z)\leq a$.

**Question:**  What are the mathematical conditions which allow us to say the function $f(z)$ must continue smoothly into $\operatorname{Re}(z)\leq a$?

---

**Notes:**  My inexpert thoughts are that

- if $f(z)$ is complex differentiable over all $z$, with only separated poles permitted, then it cannot have a discontinuity along the entire line $\operatorname{Re}(z)=a$.
- the derivatives $f'(z)$ a small distance to the right of the line at $\operatorname{Re}=a + \epsilon$, completely determine the direction of the isolines as they cross to the left of $\operatorname{Re}(z)=a$.

I would appreciate your help in grounding this intuition in concrete mathematical properties of complex functions.

---

**Background:** Although not central to this question, the question is inspired by the continuation of the Riemann Zeta **series** $\sum\frac{1}{n^s}$ which only converges for $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$, but whose isolines of the magnitude suggest the function could continue smoothly to the left of $\operatorname{Re}(s)=1$.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure *any* details/justification of analytic continuation is "suitable for a pre-university audience", but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: I have removed the "pre-university explanation" requirement.